# In science, is there such a thing as incontrovertible evidence?

Tags: experimental-physics, popular-science

Can we make *any* statement about the universe that is not open to new evidence? For example, we seem to have incontrovertible evidence that the earth is round, but could new technology 500 years from now show that we were mistaken about this?

I believe this is a scientific question, which is why I'm posting it in the physics subforum.

Comment: Physical theories (there are very few of them and most of what the public calls "a theory" is not a theory) are not open to revision. The reason for that is simple: they "work" within the limits of their validity. There is no need to revise them. Similarly, nobody would revise the navigation algorithms for passenger jet flights based on "new evidence" that the Earth is flat, for instance. Do we even have "a theory" for cosmology? No, we don't. What we have, right now, are models. Models are open to revision or they are simply being abandoned.

Comment: We are well beyond the point where the Earth could be found to be "not round" by any future discovery in science.  I sincerely hope future discoveries will explain why people cling to the absurd notion of a "not round" Earth, but they'll be discoveries in psychology, not physics.

Comment: @SvenForkbeard I do not know why this was downvoted, I think any down vote, as a matter of collegial courtesy, should be accompanied by some explanation. But I do not think that people here have aversion to "philosophy of physics", rather this SE is aimed at "physics" and the two are not the same. I am not saying that "philosophy of physics" does not matter in physics or is not interesting, it is and it does, but the two should be separated and discussed separately if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be excessively philosophical, you could preface all statements with "Provided we are capable of distinguishing most sensory observations of reality from pure fictions of the mind..." in order to make them foolproof against discoveries that we are brains in jars, hoodwinked by trickster gods, or entombed in an ever-changing Matrix with arbitrary rules.

Since *every* statement about *everything* needs that proviso to be strictly 100% true, it's safe to omit it and just say yes. The models that we have for the behavior of the universe are bounded by domains of relevance and limits on their predictive accuracy that tend to get worse the closer to the edge of their domain of relevance you get. Within those limits they are true facts about reality. Future models, with access to more or better data, will have larger domains of relevance or better predictive accuracy, but will not contradict our current models over the domains for which we have been able to exhaustively test them.

Incidentally, most solipsists don't go nearly far enough down the rabbit hole of "only 100% certainty will do". *Cognition, therefore existence* is valid, but imputing the existence of an *I* who's doing the thinking is begging the question.

Comment: In life, is there such a thing as incontrovertible evidence?

Comment: @mmesser314 I'm not 100% convinced that there's life for there to be such a thing as incontrovertible evidence in

Comment: I think the technical name for your philosophy is paranoia. But you have a point. And just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they're not out to get you. The question is are you paranoid enough?

Comment: *Are* they out to get me? Is there a they? Is there a me? Is there even *getting*?! I have fifty quadrillion measurements that suggest things are as they seem, there is a they, a me, and getting (and nobody's out to get me), but there could be sixty quadrillion measurements tomorrow that suggest otherwise! We have to weight vanishingly small probabilities as if they're practically nonzero! What if all my 40K atoms undergo spontaneous radioactive decay all at once? These bananas are bombs waiting to explode! I'm a bomb waiting to explode! We're all bombs, Morty! Bombs!